# How to use Interface in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two widgets, widget1 and widget2. 
Widget1: I have added one Drop-down in this widget. now I want to update widget2's views properties (like color and name) on drop-down item changes event.

So, Can I use interface to fulfill the above requirements? or Is there any other way to perform the same things?

```
Widget1
 - Text
 - DropdownButton
     - OnChange(){
        // Update widget2 (change txt1 & color1 values)
       }


Widget2
 - Text
 - Container
     - Card
         - Text (txt1, color1...)
```

Comment: Just make sure you call SetState in OnChange().

Comment: I had tried that but not working.

Comment: You can use InheritedWidget, ScopeModel or just set a GlobalKey<YourWidgetState> to your widget and you could access to their methods

Comment: Can you share your code what you did & what didn't work.

Comment: You can use callback functions as well.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to have a common ancestor widget that is stateful:

```
WidgetParent (StatefulWidget)
- Widget1 (displays the dropdown)
- Widget2 (displays the text/color)
```

The selection of Widget1 is passed up to the parent (using a callback). The selection is stored in the state of the parent widget, and passed down to Widget2 through constructor parameters. The parent calls `setState`, which causes all children to be rebuilt.

Example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  String _text = 'hello world';
  Color _color = Colors.red;

  void _onSelectionChanged(int value) {
    if (value == 0) {
      setState(() {
        _text = "0 selected";
        _color = Colors.blue;
      });
    } else if (value == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _text = "1 selected";
        _color = Colors.yellow;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _text = "unknown value selected";
        _color = Colors.black;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Widget1(
          onChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
        ),
        Widget2(
          text: _text,
          color: _color,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;

  const Widget1({Key key, this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Zero"), value: 0),
        DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("One"), value: 1),
      ],
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;

  const Widget2({Key key, this.text, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is pass the Function that needs to be executed 
Something like this

```
Widget1 (this._onChangeFunction); // get a ref to the Function needed later

final Function _onChangeFunction; 

 - Text
 - DropdownButton
     - OnChange(){
        // Update widget2 (change txt1 & color1 values)
        _onChangeFunction(txt, color);
      }


Widget2

fun _changeText(String txt, String color) {
   // called by Widget1, change the Text... in this private function
}

// some reference to Widget1, nested in your Card perhaps?
Widget1(_changeText);

 - Text
 - Container
     - Card
         - Text (txt1, color1...)
```

Comment: Isn't that what the earlier answer said?